# Error when `aws logs list-tags-log-group`

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Can someone show me an example of using the AWS CLI command `aws logs list-tags-log-group`?

I could use it with a log group whose name has no slash (e.g. `fooTestLogGroup`) but when I used the same command with any log group whose name has forward slashes (e.g. `/aws/codebuild/logGroup1` or `/ecs/logGroup2` then I got this error

```
An error occurred (ServiceUnavailableException) when calling the 
ListTagsLogGroup operation (reached max retries: 4): The server failed to 
fulfill the request. Please try again.
```

The command that I used was:

```
$ aws logs list-tags-log-group --log-group-name fooTestLogGroup
```

I have searched on the net and also looked up [AWS CLI Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/list-tags-log-group.html) but could not find an answer

Comment: not sure why are you getting the error , please check if these log groups exist.

Comment: I am also getting the similar error.
An error occurred (ServiceUnavailableException) when calling the ListTagsLogGroup operation (reached max retries: 4): The server failed to fulfill the request. Please try again.

Comment: Same issue. Any updates on this? @mkrana the log groups exist

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows and running this in a bash emulator (like ConEmu), that might be the source of the issue.

The issue is resolved when running the command in PowerShell.